# Java - Send an email : image / HTML and PDF attachment

Tags: java, html, image, email, attachment

Thank you for reading my post.

I need to automatically send emails which contain:

- a company logo (an image),
- an HTML message,
- a PDF attachment.

I do not manage to have both the image displayed properly in the email, and the PDF "managed properly" by the email client.

**CASE 1**
(See code below) With `multipart = new MimeMultipart("mixed");`

- the PDF attachment is managed properly by the email client:
  a little paper clip appears in the email client to indicate that email has an attachment,
  the size of the PDF attachment appears too,
  etc.
- the logo isn't displayed properly at the top of the email (within the HTML code) but at the end of the email.

**CASE 2**
(See code below) When `multipart = new MimeMultipart("related");`

This is the reverse:

- the image is displayed at the top of the email where it is supposed to be,
- but the PDF attachment is not properly handled by the email client (no paper clip in the main windows, "size unknown" for the attachment, etc.).

I regularly receive emails which contain both a logo and a PDF attachment (as most of us do).

I have noticed (in the messages source of these emails) that there usually are two parts: one multipart/mixed and one multipart/related.

I do not manage to write the code for which both the logo and the attachment are handled properly by the email client.

Below you can find the code I already wrote.

Thank you for helping and best regards.

```
public void send(String s_fromEmailAddress, String s_toEmailAddress, String s_messageSubject, String s_messageAttachmentFileName, String s_messageAttachmentFileNameToDisplay)
throws AddressException, MessagingException, IOException
{
Properties properties = null;
Session session = null;
Message message = null;
BodyPart  messageBodyPart = null;
Multipart  multipart = null;
DataSource fileDataSource = null;
String s_htmlText = null;
DataSource fds = null;

    //------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Get system properties.
    //------------------------------------------------------------------
    properties = System.getProperties();

    //------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Setup mail server.
    //------------------------------------------------------------------
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.wanadoo.fr");

    //------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Get the default Session object.
    //------------------------------------------------------------------
    session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

    //------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Define message.
    //------------------------------------------------------------------
    message = new MimeMessage(session);

    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(s_fromEmailAddress));

    message.addRecipient(
                Message.RecipientType.TO,
                new InternetAddress(s_toEmailAddress));
                message.setSubject(s_messageSubject);

    //------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Create the message part.
    //------------------------------------------------------------------
    multipart = new MimeMultipart("related");

    //------------------------------------------------------------------
    // HTML part
    //------------------------------------------------------------------
    s_htmlText =
        "<html> \n"
      + "  <head> \n"
      + "    <meta http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\"> \n"
      + "  </head> \n"
      + "  <body> \n"
      + "    <img width=\"100px\" \n"
      + "         height=\"37px\" \n"
      + "         style=\"margin-left: 1em;\" \n"
      + "         src=\"cid:image\" \n"
      + "         alt=\"LOGO\" />\n"
      + "    <br /> \n"
      +      ms_messageBodyPartText
      + "  </body> \n"
      + "</html> ";

    messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    messageBodyPart.setContent(s_htmlText, "text/html; charset=utf-8");
    messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "8bit");
    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

    //------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Logo (image)
    //------------------------------------------------------------------
    messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    fds = new FileDataSource("where_the_image_can_be_found//Logo1_25_p_cent.png");

    messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds));
    messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-ID", "<image>");
    messageBodyPart.addHeader("Content-Type", "image/png");

    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

    //------------------------------------------------------------------
    // This part is the attachment.
    //------------------------------------------------------------------
    if((s_messageAttachmentFileName != null)
    && (s_messageAttachmentFileNameToDisplay != null))
    {
        messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        fileDataSource = new FileDataSource(s_messageAttachmentFileName);
        messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fileDataSource));
        messageBodyPart.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
        messageBodyPart.setFileName(s_messageAttachmentFileNameToDisplay);
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
    }

    //------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Put parts in message.
    //------------------------------------------------------------------
    message.setContent(multipart);

    //------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Send the message
    //------------------------------------------------------------------
    Transport.send(message);
}
```

Comment: Some images are blocked by mail-clients. Do you like to have a image-table instead? http://webtools.gieskes.nl/image_to_table_converter/

Comment: Hello Peter. Thank you for the tool.
The image dimensions are 142px x 52px.
I set "Pixel Size" to (1, 1).
I set "Table Size" to (142, 52).
I checked the checkbox "Check to get all colors".
It's really not bad but it's not as "good" as the original picture...
But it's a good idea.

Comment: Hm, i guess its a bad way to do big images this way. If you foreward the mail five times, you will have 1Megabyte of table-images.

Comment: I used the http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-email/download_email.cgi library instead and I could make it work.